# Reloading Kendo UI Scheduler DataSource [TypeError: this.dataSource.expand ]

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using following code to reload the Kendo UI Scheduler datasoure

```
            var scheduler = $("#myScheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
            scheduler.dataSource = recordCollection;
```

I am getting error

TypeError: this.dataSource.expand is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the right way to change the datasource on a widget. Most of the Kendo widgets have a `.setDataSource()` function to do this.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#methods-setDataSource

This function would be used to change the DataSource to a different one.
If you just wanted to reload the data in the current DataSource (for example, re-read the data from the server) then you could instead call `.read()` on the existing DataSource:

```
scheduler.dataSource.read();
```

Comment: Thanks 'codingwithspike' , can u please help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479836/how-to-prevent-kendo-ui-shceduler-event-popup-and-show-it-in-same-page